# Use "original" rather than "variant" glyphs in Arev Math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage[origletters]{arevmath}

\begin{document}
$afuvwx$
\end{document}
```

where I'm using the `arevmath` (Arev Math) font package. On compiling it using `latexmk -xelatex arev_test.tex`, the rendered output looks like:

[image: Arev Math afuvwx]

However, according to the [manual](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/fonts/arev/arevdoc.pdf), the glyphs should look like the ones on the left side if you supply the `origletters` option while loading `arevmath`.

[image: Arev letter table]

I checked that if I explicitly type `\origa`, it does give me the expected glyph. However, if I do `\renewcommand{\vara}{\origa}` in the preamble, that doesn't fix the `a` glyph in the body. How can I get the "original" letters working as advertised in the manual?

Comment: You may have come across a bug in the package. Have you contacted the package's maintainer? His email address is provided on the first page of the package's manual

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since the package hadn't been updated in a while (with Todos still left), I thought that I might not be able to reach them. However, I've sent an email in case they have time to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Part of the problem seems to be that the package changes the symbol only if the variant condition is false, rather than doing so only if it is true. That is, the package does

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@a}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{139}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@i}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{140}
                                      \DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{111}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@I}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{138}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@f}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{154}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@l}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{141}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@u}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{142}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@v}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{143}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@w}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{144}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@x}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{145}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Gamma} {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varGamma}{\mathord}{extraup}{93}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Xi} {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varXi}{\mathord}{extraup}{94}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Pi} {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPi}{\mathord}{extraup}{95}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Sigma} {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varSigma}{\mathord}{extraup}{96}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Phi}{true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPhi}{\mathord}{extraup}{97}}
```

rather than

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@a}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{139}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@i}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{140}
                                      \DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{111}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@I}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{138}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@f}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{154}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@l}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{141}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@u}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{142}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@v}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{143}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@w}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{144}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@x}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{145}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Gamma} {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varGamma}{\mathord}{extraup}{93}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Xi} {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varXi}{\mathord}{extraup}{94}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Pi} {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPi}{\mathord}{extraup}{95}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Sigma} {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varSigma}{\mathord}{extraup}{96}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@Phi}{true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPhi}{\mathord}{extraup}{97}}{}
```

However, this can't be the whole problem else omitting `origletters` should have the effect you are trying to obtain by using it, but it obviously doesn't.

The package treats the basic maths font configuration as if it included the original rather than variant forms, but that seems not to be the case. The reason `\origa` etc. work is that these, like `\vara`, draw from `extraitalic` and not from the base set of fonts at all.

You should report this to the maintainer. However, here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[origletters]{arevmath}
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@a}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{139}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{50}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@i}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{140}
                                      \DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{111}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{58}\DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{76}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@I}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{138}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{30}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@f}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{154}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{55}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@l}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{141}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{61}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@u}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{142}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{70} }
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@v}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{143}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{71}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@w}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{144}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{72}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@x}  {true}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{145}}{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{73}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$afuvwx \origa\vara$


\end{document}
```

[image: workaround]

Comment: Thanks, this works well for the italic font :). I'm sorry I didn't mention this in the original question: would it be possible to also fix the `mathrm` glyphs? (I'd assumed that the italic fix would also fix the mathrm stuff). Right now, I'm seeing `f` replaced by `7` and `a` replaced by `2`, for example.

Comment: In more detail, with above fix, \mathrm{a} produces 2

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the package `mathastext`. If you dont mind losing the italic style in all of your equations. Since you asked for `mathrm` I think it may help you.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\[ab+xy=\dfrac{vw}{f(x)}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: equation1]

enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!